# What are the downsides of overriding `equals()` in this way?

Tags: java, equals

Consider the usual example of the immutable `ComplexNumber` class for Java (which doesn't have a `ComplexNumber` struct like C# does). Of course it's necessary to override `toString()`, `equals()` and `hashCode()`.

Unlike Scala, we can't do type matching with smart casts (that's IntelliJ Kotlin terminology). This line of thought led me to write this `equals()` override:

```
    public boolean equals(ComplexNumber other) {
        if (other == null) return false; // Thanks, Andreas
        if (Double.doubleToLongBits(this.real) != Double.doubleToLongBits(other.real)) return false;
        return Double.doubleToLongBits(this.imag) == Double.doubleToLongBits(other.imag);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) return false;
        if (this.getClass() != obj.getClass()) return false;
        return (this.equals((ComplexNumber) obj));
    }
```

For now I'm not too concerned about giving any tolerance for loss of machine precision.

In Mathematica, defining things in the wrong order can cause unexpected problems. Not so much in Java. I switched the order of the two `equals()`, added print lines and ran the tests.

```
equals(Object) invoked
equals(ComplexNumber) invoked
div
minus
times
plus
toString
equals(Object) invoked
equals(Object) invoked
equals(ComplexNumber) invoked
getRealPart
getImagPart
equals(Object) invoked
equals(ComplexNumber) invoked
equals(Object) invoked
equals(ComplexNumber) invoked
hashCode
equals(Object) invoked
equals(ComplexNumber) invoked
equals(Object) invoked
equals(ComplexNumber) invoked
equals(Object) invoked
equals(Object) invoked
equals(ComplexNumber) invoked
equals
```

Regardless of order, it passes all the relevant tests in my test class, but I get the feeling I'm not testing for something that becomes an issue if I do it this way. There's no need to create a final copy, but instead there's a need for one more thing on the call stack, so performance-wise this might be a wash if it's not an actual drain. I also get the feeling this might be a problem in the Scala REPL.

On a purely practical level, I'm perfectly content to pretty much use the standard generated `equals()` override on this one. But I am curious as to the disadvantages of doing it this way, besides that it doesn't feel idiomatic.

Comment: What do you mean by “switched the order of the two equals”? Where they’re defined in the file? Doesn’t matter—not how Java works. The order you’re calling things in “equals”? What are you asking?

Comment: @Dave I thought if I put `equals(Object)` before `equals(ComplexNumber)` it would create an infinite loop. So I was ready to start the tests and then force quit them once I saw the test runner get stuck. But that wasn't necessary.

Comment: The *physical order* of method declarations in a source file has no meaning, except to us humans, who often prefer things to be in some logical order to make the methods easier to find. It makes no difference to the Java language.

Comment: Potential flaw in your code: If a caller has `ComplexNumber c1, c2` declared, and do `c1.equals(c2)`, then normally a `false` value is returned if `c1 != null && c2 == null`, but your code will cause `NullPointerException`. Is that a major issue? For you to decide. It is an inconsistency in behavior between the two methods.

Comment: @Andreas Thank you very much for pointing that out. I've patched it up. This introduces a slight redundancy that I consider inelegant. I'm by no means DRY zealot, but I definitely consider repeating the null check a disadvantage for this manner of overriding `equals()`.

Comment: In Mathematica, if you define `kronDelta[x_, y_]` before `kronDelta[x_, x_]`, it won't work as intended.

Comment: The main problem I'd see is the confusing overload: `aComplexNumber.equals(aSubclassOfComplexNumber)` would have a different result from `aComplexNumber.equals((Object) aSubclassOfComplexNumber)`. (Use `instanceof` instead of `getClass()` to fix).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good implementation. Eric Evans in his book "domain driven design" has implemented equality of an ValueObject this way. He called the ‘equals’ as ‘sameValuAs’ to distinguish between them and overridden equals() calls `sameValueAs` similar to your implication.

I will advice to modify equals method to return false when the class type is not of type ComplexNumber using `instanceof` method. Here is an example -

```
    public boolean sameValueAs(ComplexNumber other) {
        if (other == null) return false; 
        if (Double.doubleToLongBits(this.real) != Double.doubleToLongBits(other.real)) return false;
        return Double.doubleToLongBits(this.imag) == Double.doubleToLongBits(other.imag);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if(this == obj) return true;
        if (!(obj instanceof ComplexNumber)) return false;
        return sameValueAs((ComplexNumber) obj));
    }
```

Comment: Can you specify why you would use `instanceof` instead of `getClass()`?

Comment: @Louis-JacobLebel I'm guessing for the same reason Andy Turner gave. Although maybe Andy posted his comment because of yours...

Comment: @AlonsodelArte His comment don't explain why one would prefer `instanceof` over `getClass()` in this case, but gives an example to show it. I made a little Google search: `instanceof` returns true for subclasses, where it's not the case with `getClass()`, and that's why casting `aSubclassOfComplexNumber` to `Object` would give a different result in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59803836/what-are-the-downsides-of-overriding-equals-in-this-way/59804204?noredirect=1#comment105749205_59803836).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. `obj.getClass()` will give NPE when null is passed to equals whereas `obj instanceof ComplextNumber` won't give NLP. We should avoid NLP.

Comment: Correct, there's that too; except for when the `null` keyword is nowhere to be seen in your personal projects. In this case, the remaining problem would be that `getClass` on an instance of `ComplexNumber` can return a `Class<?>` more concrete than expected (so trying to `==` two of them might yield `false` where you'd expect `true` to be yield). Also, this won't happen if all of the `class`es in your personal projects are `final`.